How to add scrollable buttons in tkinter python
Currently, I'm using a tkinter canvas to try scroll buttons. I put twenty buttons on the canvas and none of them scrolled like I expected.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randint, choice

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x400')
window.title('Scrolling Buttons')

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, scrollregion = (0,0,2000,5000))

for i in range(20):
    Button(window, text = "Start", width = 10, bg = "#b5e2ff", activebackground = "#03c04a",     activeforeground = "white", font = ("Helevetica", 10)).pack()

canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')

canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(-int(event.delta / 60), "units"))

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(window, orient = 'vertical', command = canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.place(relx = 1, rely = 0, relheight = 1, anchor = 'ne')

window.mainloop()


You are no putting the buttons inside the canvas. Use tk.Button(canvas, ...) and then call canvas.create_window(window=<button>, ...)

@TheLizzard I didn't realize that. Thanks! I'll put the buttons inside of the canvas

First of all, you have created those buttons as children of window, not canvas, so they will not be put inside the canvas.
One of the way to achieve your goal is to create a frame inside the canvas and put those buttons inside that frame. Then put that frame inside the canvas using .create_window(...).
Below is a simple example:
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x400')
window.title('Scrolling Buttons')

canvas = tk.Canvas(window)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(window, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)

# frame for those buttons
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=frame, anchor='nw', tags=('frame',))

# set the width of the frame to the same as that of the canvas
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.itemconfig('frame', width=e.width))

# update canvas scrollregion whenever the frame is resized
frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))
frame.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda e: canvas.yview_scroll(-e.delta//60, 'units'))

# add buttons to the frame
for i in range(20):
    tk.Button(frame, text=f'Start {i+1}', width=10, bg='#b5e2ff',
              activebackground='#03c04a', activeforeground='white',
              font=('Helvetica', 10)).pack(pady=2)

window.mainloop()

Result:

